# Magnific Popup with html5 video

Tags: magnific-popup

How to use magnific-popup to retrieve and popup an html5 video from my server instead of getting the video from youtube, vimo, ...?

```
<video width="500" height="350" controls>
    <source src="/static/video/bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support this video format.
</video>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have got this to work using the following as a link to open the video:

```
<a class="popup-player" href="/static/video/bunny.mp4">
 video link
</a>
```

and then used the Iframe type to display it:

```
$('.popup-player').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: false,
    iframe: {
        markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
              '</div>',

        srcAction: 'iframe_src',
        }
});
```

This is a very basic version, it opens the video in an iframe but I have yet to work out how to change the things like the height and width. I'm still learning this stuff so I dont know how it works I just know it puts a video up on the screen. If you get it working and build a more complex version please let me know so I can improve my version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post any updates here if i found a solution about it.

Answer (score 3):

This worked great for me.  Uses "Inline" type with auto-starting HTML5 video.

> Javascript:
>
> ```
> $('.openVideo').magnificPopup({
> type: 'inline',
> callbacks: {
>   open: function() {
>     $('html').css('margin-right', 0);
>     // Play video on open:
>     $(this.content).find('video')[0].play();
>     },
>   close: function() {
>     // Reset video on close:
>     $(this.content).find('video')[0].load();
>     }
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> HTML:
>
> ```
> <a href="#video-01" class="openVideo">
> <div id="video-01" class="video-popup mfp-hide">
>     <video preload="false" poster="/videos/01.png">
>         <source src="/videos/01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>     </video>
> </div>
> ```

Original source: https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/626

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check basics first:
-if the path to plugin is correct and included correctly

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script><br />

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file --><br />
<script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

> It’s not required, but we recommend placing CSS files in `<head>` and JavaScript files and initialization code in the footer of your site (before the closing `</body>` tag).
>   If you already have `jquery.js` on your site, don’t include it a second time, or use `jQuery.noConflict();` mode. Optionally, you can include Zepto.js instead of jQuery, or choose which one to include based on browser support. ACCORDING->http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

-if you have the movie on your server and if the path to it is correct.
`/` is for getting into folder

Then JS:

> `$(document).ready(function() {
>     $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
>   });`

For more information see the link I putted few lines above